# How to handle a NoSuchKey error with aws-sdk in Node

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk

I can't understand why my error handling isn't catching the 'NoSuchKey' error from S3.

It's all within a try/catch, and there's also error handling in the callback too.

What am I missing?

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({ endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint(...) });
const Key = '/this/file/doesnt/exist';
const dropboxConnection = ...

const streamFromS3 = (Key) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const fileStream = s3.getObject({ Bucket: 'mybucket', Key }).createReadStream();
            const dropboxUploadStream = dropboxConnection(
                {
                    resource: 'files/upload',
                    parameters: {
                        path: destination,
                    },
                },
                (err, result, response) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    resolve({ result, response });
                }
            );

            // This then crashes the whole app, with
            // "NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist."
            // regardless of the try/catch it's nested in

            fileStream.pipe(dropboxUploadStream);
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you're using streams, you need to add an error handler. E.g.

```js
const fileStream = s3.getObject({ Bucket: 'mybucket', Key }).createReadStream();

fileStream.on('error', (err) => reject(err));
```

When you pipe, you generally need a handler on the result of the pipe as well:

```js
fileStream.pipe(dropboxUploadStream)
  .on('error', (err) => reject(err));
```

Instead of using `pipe` directly, you can use [pipeline](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback) which essentially groups a range of piped streams together so you only need one error handler (i.e. with this, you can omit the `on('error'` above).

```js
pipeline(fileStream, dropboxUploadStream, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    reject(err);
  } else {
    resolve();
  }
});
```

And finally, starting with Node 15, you can import the promise version of pipeline from `stream/promises` (as opposed to just `stream`):

```js
import { pipeline } from 'stream/promises';

const streamFromS3 = async (Key) => {
  const readStream = s3.getObject({ Bucket: 'mybucket', Key }).createReadStream();

  const writeStream = dropboxConnection({
    resource: 'files/upload',
    parameters: {
      path: 'sdfsdf',
    },
  });

  await pipeline(readStream, writeStream);
};
```

Prior to node 15, you can use `util.promisify` to get the same effect:

```js
import { promisify } from 'util';
import { pipeline } from 'stream';

// ...
await promisify(pipeline)(readStream, writeStream);
```

Here is a bit more info about pipeline:
https://dev.to/morz/pipeline-api-the-best-way-to-handle-stream-errors-that-nobody-tells-you-about-122o